# Two responsive/flexible divs side by side

Tags: css, responsive-design, responsive

I have two responsive divs side by side.

When screen size is smaller than `600px` wide, those two divs rearrange one on top of the other, like they should do, BUT... I can't get those two divs to be `flexible` and `100%` wide when screen size gets smaller than `600px`.

I've tried flexbox and many other things but just can't get divs flexible. Anyone knows?

```css
body
{
  background-color: #fcfcfc;
}
.columns
{
  text-align: center;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-top: 0;  
}
.left-div
{
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 400px;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #ddd;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin: 5px;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.right-div
{
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 400px;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #ddd;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin: 5px;
}
.left-text, .right-text
{ text-align:justify;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) 
{
  .left-div, .right-div
    {
       max-width: 100%;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="columns">

<div class="left-div left-text">
<p> Lorem ipsum LEFT.</p>
</div>
<div class="right-div right-text">
<p> Lorem ipsum RIGHT.</p>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to also make `width:100%` in addition to specifying the `max-width:100%`. You also need to add `box-sizing:border-box;` to avoid some overflow due to the use of padding.

Check the full code, i used 800px instead of 600px so we can see the result here.

```css
body {
  background-color: #fcfcfc;
}

.columns {
  text-align: center;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-top: 0;
}

.left-div {
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 400px;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #ddd;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin: 5px;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.right-div {
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 400px;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #ddd;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin: 5px;
}

.left-text,
.right-text {
  text-align: justify;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  .left-div,
  .right-div {
    max-width: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="columns">

  <div class="left-div left-text">
    <p> Lorem ipsum LEFT.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="right-div right-text">
    <p> Lorem ipsum RIGHT.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: check your code before posting it, he want `@media screen and (max-width: 600px) ` not `@media screen and (max-width: 800px) `!

Comment: @AlaaMh it's 600px, am simply trying to change it so we can see the result in the snippet here

Answer (score 2):

Display your elements as *block* so that they can occupy the full horizontal width available, **e.g:** `display: block;`

And for good measure, declare `width: 100%`

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
      .left-div,
      .right-div {
        max-width: 100%;
        /* Additional */
        width: 100%;
        display: block;
      }
    }
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #fcfcfc;
}

.columns {
  text-align: center;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-top: 0;
}

.left-div {
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 400px;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #ddd;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin: 5px;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.right-div {
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 400px;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #ddd;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin: 5px;
}

.left-text,
.right-text {
  text-align: justify;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .left-div,
  .right-div {
    max-width: 100%;
    /* Additional */
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="columns">

  <div class="left-div left-text">
    <p> Lorem ipsum LEFT.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="right-div right-text">
    <p> Lorem ipsum RIGHT.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Or you could "Just use Flex"...

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {

  .columns {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
  }

  .left-div,
  .right-div {
    max-width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #fcfcfc;
}

.columns {
  text-align: center;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-top: 0;
}

.left-div {
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 400px;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #ddd;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin: 5px;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.right-div {
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 400px;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #ddd;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin: 5px;
}

.left-text,
.right-text {
  text-align: justify;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {

  .columns {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
  }

  .left-div,
  .right-div {
    max-width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="columns">

  <div class="left-div left-text">
    <p> Lorem ipsum LEFT.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="right-div right-text">
    <p> Lorem ipsum RIGHT.</p>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

**Heads up!** `flex-box` has poor or limited support for legacy browsers, so if this is going to be a concern for you, it's probably better not to use it in production.

IE <= 9 - *Not Supported*
IE 10,11 - *Partial Support*
**See more:** https://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox

*Edit:* As @TemaniAfif has pointed out in the comments, you should set a `border-box` property as well, **e.g:** `box-sizing: border-box`

```
.left-text,
.right-text {
  text-align: justify;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Typically, this is set as a global rule, using a *global* selector, **e.g:** `* { box-sizing: border-box; }`

> `border-box` tells the browser to account for any border and padding
>   in the value you specify for width and height. If you set an element's
>   width to 100 pixels, that 100 pixels will include any border or
>   padding you added, and the content box will shrink to absorb that
>   extra width. This typically makes it much easier to size elements.

**Want to learn more?** https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing

Comment: i think it's also useful to tell him about `border-box` as actually he will have some overflow caused by padding/margin ;)

Comment: now your answer is more than complete :) and dont tell me you are going to use your name in all the anwsers ? the "flexman" ! :p